# Passing the current_user ID through nested_attributes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have an application that has to authenticate using an external database run on .net. There is a separate Rails app, mounted as a gem that handles the authentication. When someone authenticates, their information is stored in the session object. The app itself is a type of discussion forum.

When I create an attachment through the attachments controller, all the attributes are saved to the database correctly. However, when I do it using `nested_attributes_for` in the discussions model, only the attributes defined paperclip are passed through. The `created_by` attribute is null.  Otherwise, everything else is the same.

Why is this attribute not being added to the DB?

Discussion model:

```
class Discussion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "Person", :foreign_key => "created_by"
  belongs_to :updater, :class_name => "Person", :foreign_key => "updated_by"
  belongs_to :discussion_group
  belongs_to :discussion_category
  has_many :discussion_comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :discussion_attachments, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :discussion_attachments, allow_destroy: true
  validates :discussion_group_id, on: :create, presence: :true
  validates :subject, :body, presence: :true
  validates :external_id, on: :create, uniqueness: :true
  before_create :add_external_id
  validates_associated :creator, :updater, :discussion_group,      :discussion_comments, :discussion_attachments
  scope :for_discussion_group_ids, ->(ids) {where('discussion_group_id IN (?)', ids)}
  scope :for_ext_id, ->(id) {where(external_id: id).first}

  ....
```

Discussion Attachment model:

```
ALLOWABLE_IMAGES = ["image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png"]
ALLOWABLE_APPLICATIONS = ["application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text",
"application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet",
"application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation",
"application/vnd.ms-excel",
"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
"application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
"application/vnd.ms-word", "application/pdf", "text/plain"]

class DiscussionAttachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :discussion
  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "Person", :foreign_key => "created_by"
  belongs_to :updater, :class_name => "Person", :foreign_key => "created_by"
  has_attached_file :document
  validates_attachment :document, :presence => true,
    :content_type => { :content_type => ALLOWABLE_APPLICATIONS + ALLOWABLE_IMAGES },
    :size => { :in => 0..5.megabytes }
end
```

Discussions controller:

```
class DiscussionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_discussion, only: [:show, :destroy]
  before_action :authorized_for_discussion?, only: [:show]
  before_action :authorized_to_start_discussion?, only: [:new, :create]

...

  def new
    @discussion = Discussion.new
    @discussion_group = DiscussionGroup.find(params[:discussion_group_id])
    @categories = DiscussionCategory.show.collect{|category| [category.name, category.id]}
    3.times {@discussion.discussion_attachments.build(created_by: current_user.PersonID)}
  end

  def create
    @discussion = Discussion.new(discussion_params.merge!({discussion_group_id: params[:discussion_group_id]}))
    @discussion.created_by = current_user.PersonID

    respond_to do |format|
      if @discussion.save
        flash[:success] = 'Discussion created successfully.'
        format.html { redirect_to discussion_group_discussion_path(@discussion.discussion_group, @discussion), notice: 'Discussion was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @discussion }
        Notify.new_discussion_notification(@discussion).deliver
      else
        flash[:error] = 'Discussion not created.'
        @discussion_group = DiscussionGroup.find(params[:discussion_group_id])
        3.times {@discussion.discussion_attachments.build(created_by: current_user.PersonID)}
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @discussion.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

 ...

  private

  ...

    def set_discussion
      @discussion = Discussion.find(params[:id])
    end


    def discussion_params
      params.require(:discussion).permit(:discussion_group_id, :discussion_category_id, :subject, :body, :document, discussion_attachments_attributes: [:id, :document])
    end
end
```

Discussions view:

```
=render partial: 'shared/error_messages', locals: {object: @discussion}

%h1 Create Discussion
%h4 #{@discussion_group.name }

.form-box
  =form_for @discussion, url: discussion_group_discussions_path, html: {multipart: true}, method: :post do |f|
    =f.hidden_field :discussion_group_id, value: @discussion_group.id
    .row
      .col-md-8.form-group
        =f.label :subject
        %span.required *
        =f.text_field :subject, class: "form-control", placeholder: 'Enter a subject for your discussion'

      .col-md-4.form-group
        =f.label :discussion_category, 'Discussion Category'
        =f.select :discussion_category_id, DiscussionCategory.show.collect{|category| [category.name, category.id]}, {prompt: true}, {class: 'dropselection form-control'}


    .row
      .col-md-8.form-group
        =f.label :body, "Body"
        %span.required *
        =f.text_area :body, class: "form-control", rows: 10

      .col-md-4.form-group
        %label Upload Files
        = f.fields_for :discussion_attachments, :html => {class: "form-control"} do |builder|
          = builder.file_field :document
          %br

    .form-group.row
      .col-md-12
        =f.submit 'Create', class: "btn btn-default"
        = link_to 'Cancel', discussion_group_path(@discussion_group), class: 'btn btn-default'

    .row
      .col-md-12
        %small
          %span.required *
          Denotes required fields
%br
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Welcome. When wording a question it helps to not be worried too much about being friendly or chatty. Stick closely to the facts, ask a good, well thought-out and researched question, and you'll do well. Consider your question to be an entry in a reference book, something like Wikipedia, since Stack Overflow aims to be like a cookbook of programming questions with answers that help solve the problem. It's not a conversation, it's a statement of the problem with possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Will do in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone runs across a problem like this.  Look at the rails log and figure out what the params hash looks like.  The problem I had was that due to building multiple attachment fields, :discussion_attachments_attributes pointed to a hash who's key values were the index of the array of attachments.  In my case, there were 3 fields.

So, I created a private method in the discussions controller:

```
def set_attachments_created_by
 attrs = params[:discussion][:discussion_attachments_attributes]
 attrs['0'][:created_by] = current_user.PersonID if attrs['0'].present?
 attrs['1'][:created_by] = current_user.PersonID if attrs['1'].present?
 attrs['2'][:created_by] = current_user.PersonID if attrs['2'].present?
end
```

Then in create, I call the method before I create the discussion:

```
def create
  set_attachments_created_by if params[:discussion][:discussion_attachments_attributes].present?
  @discussion = Discussion.new(discussion_params)
  @discussion.created_by = current_user.PersonID
  ....
```

There's probably a more elegant way to do this, but it works for this purpose and allows the nested_attribute to pass through to the DiscussionAttachments model.  Just remember to add :created_by in the strong parameters declaration.